# Div Fill Parent Container

Tags: html, css

I have a comment something like what I have mocked up below. `.avatar` & `.actions` have a static width. `.comment` does not. How should I structure my HTML & CSS so that `.text` will take up all of the available space as `.comment` changes it's width?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

psuedo  (untested) code

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <div class="actions"></div>
    <div class="text"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.avatar {float: left;}
.actions {float: right;}
.comment, .text {overflow: hidden;}
```

### [Working Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/dwakT/)

```
.avatar {
   float: left; 
   margin-right: 10px; 
   width: 100px; 
   height: 100px; 
   background: #fff;
}
.actions {
   float: right; 
   margin-left: 10px; 
   width: 30px; 
   height: 130px; 
   background: #fff;
}

.comment, .text {
   overflow: hidden;
}
.comment {
   background: #eee; 
   width: 600px; 
   padding: 10px;
}
.text {
   background: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="comment">
    <div class="avatar">..</div>
    <div class="actions">..</div>
    <div class="text">Your comment goes here<br>more text<br>more text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think clairesuzy's method is much better. Instead of setting margins like I did her/his method uses `overflow:hidden` to make sure text doesn't go below either of the floated elements. This has the advantage of not needing to hard code the widths of the two floats as margins. Adding this method to my toolbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/HggL2/2/

The fiddle above shows you how I would do it. Float `.avatar` left and `.actions` right. Give `.text` left and right margins equal to the widths of `.avatar` and `.actions` (this will prevent the text inside of `.text` from going underneath either of those). The order of everything is important so that `.actions` doesn't appear on a new line in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just use a [Flex Box](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (pure CSS) and write a lot less code.